# How to make autocomplete textbox that passes a value to another aspx page on submit?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have a website that has products list page and product detail page .

In the asp master page i placed a textbox to search the products in the database .

what i need to do is : when the visitor begins writing in the textbox ,the textbox auocompletes from the products names in the database .

when the visitor press enter on a result from the dropdownlist , the site takes him to the product details page filled by the submitted product details from the ID that is passed by the query string from the home page .

please help me i searched a lot and there are very similar questions that didn't work for my case .

any link to a tutorial or another question like mine here would be perfect .

thank you very much

Comment: You'll need to show us some code to figure out why the many similar answers don't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need automcompleteextender. Read about it in

1. codeproject tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71338/Using-the-AutoComplete-Extender-to-Automatically-P)
2. Official documentation [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)
3. MSDN tutorial covering exactly your needs [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2007/06/19/how-to-use-a-key-value-pair-in-your-autocompleteextender.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the [jQuery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

You could use it like this:

```
$('#<%= yourTextBox.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
    source: 'HandlerThatReturnsProductNames.ashx',
    select: function (event, ui) {
        // this is where you would jump to your product page
    }
});
```

And then you would need to create the generic handler "HandlerThatReturnsProductNames.ashx".  In the `ProcessRequest` method it would need to do something like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {

    string term = context.Request.QueryString.Get("term");

    List<QuickProduct> listOfProducts = SomeMethodThatGetsMatchingProducts(term);
    var jsSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = jsSerializer.Serialize(listOfProducts);

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.Write(json);
    context.Response.End();
}
```

Assuming your `QuickProduct` is something like this:

```
public class QuickProduct {
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
}
```